# The primitive of a function with modulus...

Tags: functions, definite-integrals

How do I calculate the integral such a function:

$f(x)=\mid x^2-2x \mid$ knowing that $f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$

Generally I know to calculate the integral of modulus functions when I know the exact borders , but in this case I don't know. It's obvious that the modulus will split into two and we'll have two different functions for respective intervals. I just need a hint, not the exercise solved. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $x^2-2x=x(x-2).\;$ Thus the zeros of $f$ are $0$ and $2$. Consider the three ranges $x\le0,\quad 0 < x \le 2, \quad x>2$.

Edit: Additonally to the two situations from the comments you maybe want a 'semi-definite' integral like this:
$$
\int_0^x (t^2 - 2t) dt = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{3}x^3-x^2 &x <= 0,\\
-\frac{1}{3}x^3+x^2 &0< x <= 2,\\
\frac{1}{3}x^3-x^2+\frac{8}{3} &2 < x
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: For the second range I understand, but how do I calculate the integral for x<0 or x>2, not knowing the left and respectively the right border?

Comment: It depends: If you have a definite integral integral you add the contributions from the three sections. If you want antiderivatives  you have three of them according to the three cases.

Comment: Just edited the answer to give another result.